# automatic datasheet information extraction

Tags: datasheet

Does anyone know of a way to extract information from a datasheet table ? An example of what I'd like to do is automate the comparison of a given characteristic (say V_dss) from multiple MOSFET datasheets (PDF, may be from different vendor).

The aim is to simplify the obsolete components replacement, a task that I will have to do regularly from now...

Comment: Actually, the difference between this and the generic OCR/data extraction problem is knowledge of the nature of the data being extracted.  And experiential knowledge of the tendency for key gotchas to be hidden in oddly phrased notes.  In other words, the question is fine, but the answer is that it's probably not a good idea.  Although subject to the same concern of missing critical notes, an easier to implement idea could be scraping catalog comparative paramater charts, especially the online ones.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out in the comments to your question, reading information from databases is difficult as it is not purely numbers but footnotes that require a human's understanding.

It might be easier to interface with a database or the website of a large distributer like digikey or radiospares to narrow down the likely choices and then have an engineer look at the remaining datasheets.